# Generate a word document in the server's file system in PHP

Tags: php, ms-word

I need to solve this problem soon. I tried many solutions, but all the tutorials and samples create the document and download the word file into local computer. what I want is to upload or save it to the file system of the server. Please help me to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is a little ambiguous. You want to write a php script that generates a word document? And that php script sits in your server or your local computer?

Comment: I want to create a word document using php and save that document in server not in my local computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPWord can do this:

http://phpword.codeplex.com/releases/view/49543

I have tried **Examples/BasicTable.php**, it creates the file on the server and doesn't download it.

Here's the code used:

```
<?php
require_once '../PHPWord.php';

// New Word Document
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();

// New portrait section
$section = $PHPWord->createSection();

// Add table
$table = $section->addTable();

for($r = 1; $r <= 10; $r++) { // Loop through rows
    // Add row
    $table->addRow();

    for($c = 1; $c <= 5; $c++) { // Loop through cells
        // Add Cell
        $table->addCell(1750)->addText("Row $r, Cell $c");
    }
}

// Save File
$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('BasicTable.docx');
?>
```